# delete second row of pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have been trying everything: reset index, etc.

The first level of my row index is a list of dates and the second level is simply [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. I need to delete the second row index as it is causing problems with plot format.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `droplevel()`:

```
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],['one', 'three', 'one', 'six',]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 4),columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['foo', 'bar']))
```

like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
```

or for rows:

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(1)
```